# A simple proof that $\bigl(1+\frac1n\bigr)^n\leq3-\frac1n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The inequality
$$
e_n:=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\leq3-\frac1n,
$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$, is certainly true, because we know, how LHS is connected with $e$. The other argument is the standard proof of boundedness of $(e_n)$, which uses the binomial theorem.

Are there any more elementary proofs of this inequality?

Comment: What's the question exactly, that this is $e^1<=3$? Or for all n?

Comment: @AlecTeal The question is inequality for all $n$. (In hope that it may be an alternative way of obtaining the properties od $(e_n)$).

Comment: That says "induction" to me.

Comment: @AlecTeal To me too, but without a success.

Comment: I saw $e_n$ proven to be bounded by comparing it to $f_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$, where you get $e_n<e_{n+1}<f_{n+1}<f_n$, but this only helps you for $n\geq 9$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke post what you tried (so others can avoid the same mistake)

Comment: If you show that $e_n$ is increasing with limit $e\lt 2.75$ you have that this is true for $n\ge 4$ and just need to test the cases $1,2,3$ which are straightforward

Comment: Got it! will post answer now

Comment: Posted answer, want me to write it up?

Comment: Would you please check over the two induction proofs given;  I don't think either of them is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use induction.

For $n=1$, clearly $2 \leq 2$. Assume it holds for some $n-1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Then,

$$\left(1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n-1} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \leq \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n-1} \right)^{n-1} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \leq \left( 3- \frac{1}{n-1} \right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = 3 - \frac{3}{n} - \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n(n-1)}.$$

It is left to show

$$-\frac{3}{n} - \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \leq -\frac{1}{n}$$

or equivalently

$$ -3n+3-n+1 \leq -n+1,$$

i.e. $n \geq 1$. Since $n-1 \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \geq 2$ by choice, so the inequality holds.

Comment: I have different inequality in the last line, but also true. +1. I am still waiting for another proofs, and then I'll choose the one for accepting.

Comment: By multiplying both sides of the second last inequality with $n(n-1)$, we get $-3(n-1) - n + 1 \leq -(n-1)$ which is equivalent to $-3n + 3 - n + 1 \leq -n + 1$, and by adding $3n-3$ to both sides, I ended up with $-n+1 \leq 2n-2$, if you're wondering. It seems simpler to just add $n-1$ to both sides, to retrieve $n \geq 1$ immediately. I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: How did you get the factor of $1-\frac{1}{n}$ in the first line?

Comment: I don't believe the inequality on the top line is correct for all n; for example, $(1+\frac{1}{3})^3=\frac{64}{27}>\frac{5}{3}=(3-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})$.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The factor of $1+1/n$ magically changes to $1-1/n$, strengthening the proved inequality.

Comment: @mjqxxxx To me this seems more like a fatal flaw than strengthening the proved inequality. I don't see (at least at the moment) how this proof could be salvaged as if we proceed with $1+\frac{1}{n}$ - we get $3n-5 \leq 0$ which does not lead to the inductive step.

Answer (score 7):

Since $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, we have:
$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t}\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \leq \exp\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)\leq\frac{e}{1+\frac{1}{2n+2}}=\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}e \tag{2}$$
that is stronger than $ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \leq 3-\frac{1}{n}$ for any $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Very interesting method. +1. And now I have the problem, if I should accept this one or the most elementary one. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you about this, but how did you get the last inequality in (2)?

Comment: @user84413: it is just a consequence of $e^x\geq 1+x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand.

Answer (score 4):

We can expand using Binomial Theorem:

$\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{k!} \le \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$

Now, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \le 2 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = 3 - \frac{1}{n}$

which proves the required inequality.

Comment: Yes, we can, but I am trying to find more elementary proof.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke *more* elementary ? :) Then you must help me here, what kind of proof are you looking for and what all am I allowed to use so that you may call it elementary ? :-)

Comment: `The other argument is the standard proof of boundedness of  $(e_n)$, which uses the binomial theorem.

Are there any more elementary proofs of this inequality?` I feel, that there must be a nonstandard proof. Well, one of them have already appeared.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke oops ! so this is the proof using Binomial Thereom that you mentioned in OP. Thanks ! I'll try think of a different way ! :)